# WebSphere 6.1 Increase Server Start timeout above 300 seconds

Tags: websphere, websphere-6

I'm maintaining some legacy code (dont ask), and my EAR file takes so long to load i hit the 300 second timeout, where the server starts but doesnt deploy the EAR. Then If i click publish, it deploys correctly because it saved precious seconds of having to startup the application server.

One would think double clicking on the server i would be able to edit the timeout there, like in JBoss, but all i See are the following tabs: General, Automatic Publishing, Server, Publishing, Security, and Network Deployment. None of these mention timeout anywhere. Looking inside the WAS console, there are just too many tabs and links to effectively find it by guessing.

Please help! Is anyone still alive to know this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the setting in Preferences -> Server. Its a drop down box that says

Server timeout delay: [Shorter, Short, Normal, Long, Longer]

Answer (score 2):

While not explicitly a timeout value, there's an option you can select on the application called "Launch application before server completes startup" (in the "Startup properties" page of the application config), which sets a flag telling the server not to wait for that app to start before the server continues its startup process.  I'm not positive whether it's installation of the app or the app's startup that's the issue here - "deploy" implies the former, but that's not an automatic part of server startup.  This property doesn't affect installation, just startup.

I will make an obligatory remark on WAS 6.1 being deeply out of service, but I assume based on the tone of your question that that part of the equation is out of your hands.